# Can't see the Chinese characters in VIM

Tags: vim, character-encoding, chinese

I find that when I type Chinese characters (encoded with UTF-8) into VIM, I cannot see them at all while they do exist there. I can copy and paste them into other text editors and it seems everything is fine. How can I fix this problem?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

you are not using a font which contains the glyphs needed to display the characters you typed.

so, choose the right font via

```
:set guifont=*
```

or

```
:set guifontwide=*
```

which would pop up a font-selection-dialog. and once you have a working font make it permanent by putting

```
set guifont=YOURFONT
```

to your .gvimrc / .vimrc

Comment: Neither of these worked for me on Debian with `VIM - Vi IMproved 7.3 (2010 Aug 15, compiled Feb 10 2013 02:28:47)`. No font-selection-dialog appeared.

Comment: @Mike: `guifont` settings are for `gvim`. are you using console-vim? if so: consult the manual of your terminal-program (which is responsible for drawing glyphs).

Comment: Ahh, didn't notice that little detail.

Answer (score 4):

Open the VIM configuration file

```
$ sudo -H gedit /etc/vim/vimrc
```

Added following lines:

```
set fileencodings=utf-8,ucs-bom,gb18030,gbk,gb2312,cp936
set termencoding=utf-8
set encoding=utf-8
```

Save and exit, and terminal command:

```
$ source /etc/vim/vimrc
```

At this time VIM will correctly display Chinese.

Comment: Could you explain about the line `set fileencoding=utf-8,ucs-bom,gb18030,gbk,gb2312,cp936`?

Comment: @Niing a bit late to the party, but I found and explanation here (last part of the document): https://titanwolf.org/Network/Articles/Article?AID=a4d8c31e-438c-4a8e-9ff1-75fe324acaf1#gsc.tab=0